# My website won't load when trying to implement localstorage

Tags: angular, clion, web-storage

I am using Angular 9, localStorageService from Webstorage 6, and CLion.

I have created three services: YoutubeService, MyLocalStorageService,and VideoService. YoutubeService calls the youtube data api, then it calls the MyLocalStorageService functions that take that data and store the appropriate information into localstorage. Video Service pulls from MyLocalStorageService to get the information that the rest of the components need.

I type console.log at the beginning of each MyLocalStorageService function and after the data is saved. Doing this, it seems to me that the data is being properly stored. As in, when I open dev tools and go to application I can see the data is there and correct.

The problem is that the page won't load. There is no error message in the console, and neither the header nor nav bar will load. Also, the way that I have the routing set up, when I run ng serve in the CLion terminal, localhost is supposed to redirect to '/homepage'. However, this doesn't even happen.

segment of YoutubeService.ts

```
callAPI(nextPageToken?): Observable<any> {
    let url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${this.apiKey}&channelId=${this.channelId}
    &order=date&part=snippet &type=video,id&maxResults=15`;
    if (nextPageToken) {
        url += `&pageToken=${nextPageToken}`;
    }
    return this.http.get<YTAPIObject>(url)
        .pipe(map(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.localStorageService.addConfiguration(res);
         console.log(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('configuration'));
          return res.items;
        }));
  }

    getYTVidsFromAPI(nextPage?: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.callAPI(nextPage).subscribe(
                result => this.apiResult = result,
                (err) => console.log(err),
                () => {
                    this.localStorageService.addVideos(this.apiResult);
                console.log(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('videos'));
                });
        });
    }
```

segment of MyLocalStorageService.ts

```
public addVideos(items) {
    const videos: Video[] = [];
    console.log('addVideos: Hello');
    items.forEach(obj => {
      const id = obj.id;
      const snippet = obj.snippet;
      const video: Video = {id, snippet};
      videos.push(video);
    });
    this.storage.store('videos', videos);
  }

  public addConfiguration(apiResult) {

      console.log('addConfiguration: Hello');
      const configuration = {
          nextPage: apiResult.nextPageToken,
          itemsPerPage: apiResult.pageInfo.resultsPerPage,
          totalItems: apiResult.pageInfo.totalResults
      };
      this.storage.store('configuration', configuration);
  }
```

segment of VideoService.ts

```
import { MyLocalStorageService } from './my-local-storage.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VideoService {


  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
              private localStorageService: MyLocalStorageService,
  ) { }

  getVideos(nextPage?: any): Observable<any>{
    console.log(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('videos'));
    if (nextPage) {
      return of(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('videos'));
    } else {
      return of(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('videos'));
    }
  }

  getConfigInfo(): any {
    console.log(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('videos'));
    return of(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('configuration'));
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please paste your code as text in a code block. This will make it easier to read and allows copy/pasting if someone wants to try to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I didn't resolve the promise.

```
    getYTVidsFromAPI(nextPage?: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.callAPI(nextPage).subscribe(
                result => this.apiResult = result,
                (err) => console.log(err),
                () => {
                    this.localStorageService.addVideos(this.apiResult);
              console.log(this.localStorageService.storage.retrieve('videos'));
                     resolve(true); // This should have been included
                });
        });
    }
```